# Force HTML table to exceed div width: CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

This question is asking the *opposite* of what usually is desired: a fixed-width table that exceeds the width of its parent div(s).

In fact, the following implementation works as expected in Chrome/Chromium based browsers:

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  width: 1040px;
  /* Full-width */
  table-layout: fixed;
}


/* This is intended to be in a media query for screens less than 768 px */

#myTable {
  width: 745px;
  /* Full-width + 225px */
}

td:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 51.9px;
}

td:nth-child(2),
th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 158.783px;
}

td:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 225px;
}

td:nth-child(4),
th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 78.2667px;
}

td:nth-child(5),
th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 116.15px;
}

td:nth-child(6),
th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 100.833px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 5px; width: 540px;">
  <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:right;">col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>col6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
        <td>col5</td>
        <td>col6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
        <td>col5</td>
        <td>col6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
        <td>col5</td>
        <td>col6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, when checking in Firefox and Microsoft Edge, the specified table/column widths are not honored, instead conforming to the parent div.

Most suggested solutions I've found appear to recommend applying `table-layout: fixed;` rule to the table, however, it's already applied in this example to no effect.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If it would help, the full page example is available here: [http://qkflies.tk/tableExceedDiv_demo](http://qkflies.tk/tableExceedDiv_demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I use a class/ID wrapper and based on the max-width of the wrapper assign the table's width:100% which will then create the scrollbar effect with the overflow:scroll hidden property which is what I think you're looking for? If you  want vertical scroll.

I never use the table-layout fixed attribute which would seem to be the problem., but then again I don't use it.

Just assign the table CSS at width:100% and use the @media with the table's wrapper based on screen size. This will work great for the column's adaptations too. You will just have to adjust accordingly.

By assigning the parent div's width inline you are creating somewhat of a roadblock for your responsive css capabilities as you cannot override inline styles. I'd change that approach.

```
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
}

 .tbl_wrapper{max-width: 540px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
   <!--Do some edits based on screen size //-->
.tbl_wrapper{max-width: 540px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1040px){
   <!--Do some edits based on screen size //-->
.tbl_wrapper{max-width: 640px;}
}


<div class="tbl_wrapper" style="background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 5px;">
     <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1">
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Part of the reason why I went with `table-layout: fixed;` is because I needed a sticky/fixed header (not included in snippet, but included in full page example), and thus needed to explicitly specify the widths of each column.

In the full page example, I do believe that the div's width is assigned by id/class... I was just trying to save time in constructing the snippet (shame on me for being careless).

Comment: Oh, ok. Yea fixed headers can be an issue. May I suggest using dataTables? I have a fixedHeader implementation I can possibly share with you for that,

Comment: [dataTables fixed headers](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/header_footer.html) would be my approach.Hopefully you have ability to add apis

Comment: We have a crazy setup at work that I have been working on and we have to do some crazy stuff with fixed headers. We extend on the dataTables api and everytime the window resizes we have to rebuild the fixed header. If you take a look in chrome developer dataTables uses the wrapper approach and the fixed header works great. Depending on where you want that fixed header you may have to override some things and use offset height of window to the table header.

Comment: Oh wow, that looks a lot cleaner and simpler. Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: Anytime my friend. DataTables can be your friend. dataTables is created by one person and it is the best table api available IMHO.

Comment: Also check out [dataTable.fixedHeader.adjust method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedHeader.adjust())